# Why is the root different for the same character in my trie set-up? And how can I print the trie itself?

Tags: python, trie

I am setting up a `trie`, here is my code:

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = {}
        self.endSymbol = "*"

    def add(self, word):
        node = self.root
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in node:
                node[letter] = {}
            node = node[letter]
        node[self.endSymbol] = word

def multiStringSearch(smallStrings):
    trie = Trie()

    for word in smallStrings:
        trie.add(word)

    return trie

print(multiStringSearch(["abc", "mnopqr", "wyz", "no", "e", "tuuv","abb"])
```

Two questions:

1. How can I `print out the trie`?
2. For some reason, the above doesn't produce the correct trie, for example, `"mnopqr"` and `"no"` should be under the `same root` for the `'n'`, but they appear separately by the above construction.

Thanks John and Ervin for your contributions, can I just check then, which of the following would the trie set-up produce?:

[image]

Comment: Since `"mnopqr"` and `"no"` share no common prefix, why should the both be under `'n'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. For printing out the `trie`:

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = {}
        self.endSymbol = "*"

    def add(self, word):
        node = self.root
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in node:
                node[letter] = {}
            node = node[letter]
        node[self.endSymbol] = word

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.root)


def multiStringSearch(smallStrings):
    trie = Trie()

    for word in smallStrings:
        trie.add(word)

    return trie


if __name__ == "__main__":
    trie = multiStringSearch(["abc", "mnopqr", "wyz", "no", "e", "tuuv","abb"])
    print(trie)
```

2. No, they should not be under the same root, because they do not share a common prefix. In your example `abb` and `abc` should be under the same root, and they are if you print out the `trie.

Comment: Thanks Ervin, could you also kindly briefly explain when to use the if __name__ == " __main__"? I read the following article but still couldn't understand when to use it: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/if-name-main-python-example/

Comment: You may want to check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FRxDmVVm0d0&ab_channel=anthonywritescode  or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60017299/7661119 In short, it is not something necessary to have in smaller scripts. I personally use it, because Pycharm IDE recognizes it as an entrypoint for my script.

Comment: Basically, the code bellow the scope `if __name__ == "__main__"` is executed only if I invoke my script from the terminal or from an IDE. This can help me to have a `main` function (entrypoint if you coded in C/C++) for my script, but I also can be import the functions from my script in other scripts, for example when I want to unit test something.

Answer (score 0):

ad 1) The following code will print the tree with indentation (for easier examination of the tree)

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = {}
        self.endSymbol = "*"

    def add(self, word):
        node = self.root
        for letter in word:
            if letter not in node:
                node[letter] = {}
            node = node[letter]
        node[self.endSymbol] = word

    def __str__(self):
        return self.__format(self.root)

    def __format(self, node, indent = 0):
        s = ''

        for key in node:
            s += ' ' * indent
            s += key
            if key == self.endSymbol:
                s += ' => ' + node[key]
                s += '\n'
            else:
                s += '\n'
                s += self.__format(node[key], indent + 1)

        return s

def multiStringSearch(smallStrings):
    trie = Trie()

    for word in smallStrings:
        trie.add(word)

    return trie

print(multiStringSearch(["abc", "mnopqr", "wyz", "no", "e", "tuuv","abb"]))
```

Output:

```
a
 b
  c
   * => abc
  b
   * => abb
m
 n
  o
   p
    q
     r
      * => mnopqr
w
 y
  z
   * => wyz
n
 o
  * => no
e
 * => e
t
 u
  u
   v
    * => tuuv
```